# Angular ui-router reload child controller, but doesn't do for parent

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular `ui-router`. I have a parent `state` called *panel*. I have another state called *panel.dashboard* (child of *panel*)

*Panel* 's controller never reinitialize, but *panel.dashboard* always initialize when I change the state. (Of course I change the state into child states. So, it's reasonable that parent's controller never reinitialize)

How can we control them? For example, caching the child state. Is it possible at all? Also Ionic framework has **cache** when you define the state, but it seems this is not a part of `ui-router`. It doesn't work and I can't find something about `cache` in it's documentation. Is it a part of Ionic or `ui-router`?

Comment: We will need to see your code in order to help

Comment: try cache:false in your routing definition

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi As I mentioned, it doesn't work.